# Sorting a List dynamically using attributes provided at Runetime

Tags: java, list, sorting, hashmap, comparator

There's a Map with keys of type `String` as the and values represented by a list of objects as follows:

```
Map<String, List<ScoreAverage>> averagesMap
```

`ScoreAverage` **record**:

```
public record ScoreAverage(
    @JsonProperty("average") double average,
    @JsonProperty("name") String name
) {}
```

The **map** holds data as follows :

```
{
 "averagesMap":{
  "A":[
     {
        "average":4.0,
        "name":"Accounting"
     },
     {
        "average":4.0,
        "name":"company-wide"
     },
     {
        "average":4.0,
        "name":"Engineering"
     }
  ],
  "B":[
     {
        "average":3.0,
        "name":"Engineering"
     },
     {
        "average":3.0,
        "name":"company-wide"
     },
     {
        "average":3.0,
        "name":"Accounting"
     }
  ],
  "C":[
     {
        "average":2.0,
        "name":"company-wide"
     },
     {
        "average":2.0,
        "name":"Engineering"
     },
     {
        "average":2.0,
        "en":"Accounting"
     }
  ],
  "specialAverages":[
     {
        "average":2.5,
        "name":"Engineering"
     },
     {
        "average":2.5,
        "name":"company-wide"
     },
     {
        "average":2.5,
        "name":"Accounting"
     }
   ]
  }
}
```

What I want to achieve is to sort dynamically each list of objects in a map using the `name` attribute in the order specified at runtime, for instance:

```
1st item of list -> company-wide
2nd item of list -> Engineering
3rd item of list -> Accounting
```

What would be the easiest way of doing this?

Comment: What do you mean with `dynamically sort` ? You want sort once you have read and in memory `averagesMap` or you want have all sorted right after reading the JSON ?

Comment: @PeterMmm JSON is just the way I used to display the data. value for `name` is dynamic, but its common for all the lists, which means all the lists got the same name values. So i want to sort each list for `name` field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve that, first you need to establish the desired order. So that it will be encapsulated in a variable and passed as a parameter at runtime to the method that will take care of sorting. With that, sorting order will be dynamic, dependent on the provided argument.

In the code below, a `List` is being used for that purpose. Sorting is based on the indexes that each `name` occupies in the `sortingRule` list.

The next step is to create `Comparator` based on it. I'm using a condition `sortingRule.contains(score.name())` as precaution for the cases like typo, etc. when `name` doesn't appear in the `sortingRule`. With that, all such objects will be placed at the end of a sorted list.

```
 Comparator<ScoreAverage> dynamicComparator =
            Comparator.comparingInt(score -> sortingRule.contains(score.name()) ?
                                    sortingRule.indexOf(score.name()) : 
                                    sortingRule.size());
```

If we drop the condition comparator boils down to

```
Comparator.comparingInt(score -> sortingRule.indexOf(score.name()));
```

With that, all unidentified objects (if any) will be grouped at the beginning of a sorted list.

And finally, we need to sort every value in a map with this comparator.

**Iterative implementation** (*note: defensive copy of every list is meant to preserve the source intact*).

```
public static Map<String, List<ScoreAverage>> sortByRule(Map<String, List<ScoreAverage>> averagesMap,
                                                         List<String> sortingRule) {
    Comparator<ScoreAverage> dynamicComparator =
            Comparator.comparingInt(score -> sortingRule.contains(score.name()) ?
                    sortingRule.indexOf(score.name()) :
                    sortingRule.size());

    Map<String, List<ScoreAverage>> result = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<ScoreAverage>> entry: averagesMap.entrySet()) {
        List<ScoreAverage> copy = new ArrayList<>(entry.getValue());
        copy.sort(dynamicComparator);
        result.put(entry.getKey(), copy);
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Stream based implementation** (*note: lists in the source map will not get modified, each entry will be replaced with a new one*).

```
public static Map<String, List<ScoreAverage>> sortByRule(Map<String, List<ScoreAverage>> averagesMap,
                                            List<String> sortingRule) {

     Comparator<ScoreAverage> dynamicComparator =
            Comparator.comparingInt(score -> sortingRule.contains(score.name()) ?
                                    sortingRule.indexOf(score.name()) : 
                                    sortingRule.size());

    return averagesMap.entrySet().stream()
            .map(entry -> Map.entry(entry.getKey(),
                    entry.getValue().stream()
                    .sorted(dynamicComparator)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue));
}
```

**main()**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, List<ScoreAverage>> averagesMap =
            Map.of("A", List.of(new ScoreAverage(4.0, "Accounting"),
                                    new ScoreAverage(4.0, "company-wide"),
                                    new ScoreAverage(4.0, "Engineering")),
                   "B", List.of(new ScoreAverage(3.0, "Engineering"),
                                    new ScoreAverage(3.0, "company-wide"),
                                    new ScoreAverage(3.0, "Accounting")),
                   "C", List.of(new ScoreAverage(2.0, "company-wide"),
                                    new ScoreAverage(2.0, "Engineering"),
                                    new ScoreAverage(2.0, "Accounting")),
                   "specialAverages", List.of(new ScoreAverage(2.5, "Engineering"),
                                    new ScoreAverage(2.5, "company-wide"),
                                    new ScoreAverage(2.5, "Accounting")));

    List<String> sortingRule = List.of("company-wide", "Engineering", "Accounting");

    sortByRule(averagesMap, sortingRule).forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " : " + v));
}
```

**Output**

```
A : [ScoreAverage[average=4.0, name=company-wide], ScoreAverage[average=4.0, name=Engineering], ScoreAverage[average=4.0, name=Accounting]]
B : [ScoreAverage[average=3.0, name=company-wide], ScoreAverage[average=3.0, name=Engineering], ScoreAverage[average=3.0, name=Accounting]]
C : [ScoreAverage[average=2.0, name=company-wide], ScoreAverage[average=2.0, name=Engineering], ScoreAverage[average=2.0, name=Accounting]]
specialAverages : [ScoreAverage[average=2.5, name=company-wide], ScoreAverage[average=2.5, name=Engineering], ScoreAverage[average=2.5, name=Accounting]]
```

---

**Update**

It's also possible to combine the *sorting rule* encapsulated in a list and `Comparator` that will responsible for sorting elements that are not present in the *sorting rule*. Both *sorting rule* and a comparator will be provided dynamically at runtime.

For that, the method signature has to be changed (the third parameter needs to be added):

```
public static Map<String, List<ScoreAverage>> sortByRule(Map<String, List<ScoreAverage>> averagesMap,
                                                         List<String> sortingRule,
                                                         Comparator<ScoreAverage> downstreamComparator)
```

And the comparator will look like that:

```
Comparator<ScoreAverage> dynamicComparator =
                Comparator.<ScoreAverage>comparingInt(score -> sortingRule.contains(score.name()) ?
                                            sortingRule.indexOf(score.name()) :
                                            sortingRule.size())
                                .thenComparing(downstreamComparator);
```

It will group all objects with names *contained* in the `sortingRule` at the beginning of the resulting list, the rest part will be sorted in accordance with the `downstreamComparator`.

Method call in the main will look like that:

```
sortByRule(averagesMap, sortingRule, Comparator.comparing(ScoreAverage::name))
                .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " : " + v));
```

If you apply these changes with and provide a `sortingRule` containing only one string `"company-wide"` you'll this **output**:

```
A : [ScoreAverage[average=4.0, name=company-wide], ScoreAverage[average=4.0, name=Accounting], ScoreAverage[average=4.0, name=Engineering]]
B : [ScoreAverage[average=3.0, name=company-wide], ScoreAverage[average=3.0, name=Accounting], ScoreAverage[average=3.0, name=Engineering]]
C : [ScoreAverage[average=2.0, name=company-wide], ScoreAverage[average=2.0, name=Accounting], ScoreAverage[average=2.0, name=Engineering]]
specialAverages : [ScoreAverage[average=2.5, name=company-wide], ScoreAverage[average=2.5, name=Accounting], ScoreAverage[average=2.5, name=Engineering]]
```

Comment: Any suggestion to get the `sortingRule` dynamically from the data itself?

Comment: You mean to analyze the data somehow and establish criteria for sorting? Can you elaborate your idea on how the data could "know" how to sort itself. Based on frequency?

Comment: `company-wide` should come first. And others can be alphabetical.

Comment: @dineshalwis `others can be alphabetical` - If this order will be hard-coded inside the method, then it'll be only *partially dynamic*. The solution will be more flexible if the order of elements that are not mentioned in the `sortingRule` list, will be defined by a `Comparator` that will be provided at *runtime* as well as a sorting rule.